# presentRenderbuffer using memory?

Tags: ipad, opengl-es

I have simple drawing code like the following - repeated calls to draw several objects, 
followed by one call to glBindRenderbufferOES and one call to presentRenderbuffer -

Objects draw fine, BUT - the call to presentRenderBuffer allocates a good amount
of memory with each call

I've generated and bound frame and render buffers - once - then never really do anything
with them after that -

Should I be clearing my buffers after each call to presentRenderBuffer? Or is there
some other way to give back memory after calling?

```
// these four calls made for each object
Loop over objects
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, ...
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, ...
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, ...
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,...

// then, one-time call to these
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```